C# - Getting "codec cannot use the type of stream provided" When Reading A .bmp File
I am trying to use BMPBitMapDecoder to read .bmp files in a directory. But, no matter what I try, I get "codec cannot use the type of stream/URI provided" exception.
Things I have tried so far:
1) Following Documentation Of Microsoft To Use URI: I have followed the uri example and wrote something like this:
myPath = "C:\\MyImages\\";
imagesInDir = Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.bmp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

Uri imgURI = new Uri(imagesInDir[0]);
BmpBitmapDecoder bmpImgDec = new BmpBitmapDecoder(imgURI, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bmpSource = bmpImgDec.Frames[0];

Result: I got the "codec cannot use the type of URI provided" exception.
2) Following Documentation Of Microsoft To Use File Stream: I have followed the file stream example and wrote something like this:
myPath = "C:\\MyImages\\";
imagesInDir = Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.bmp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

FileStream imgFS = new FileStream(imagesInDir[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
BmpBitmapDecoder bmpImgDec = new BmpBitmapDecoder(imgFS, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bmpSource = bmpImgDec.Frames[0];

Result: I got the "codec cannot use the type of stream provided" exception.
3) Using Block To Use Stream: I wrote something like this:
myPath = "C:\\MyImages\\";
imagesInDir = Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "*.bmp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

using (Stream imgFS = new FileStream(imagesInDir[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)){
    BmpBitmapDecoder bmpImgDec = new BmpBitmapDecoder(imgFS, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    BitmapSource bmpSource = bmpImgDec.Frames[0];
}

Result: I got the "codec cannot use the type of stream provided" exception.
4) Using BitmapDecoder Instead Of BmpBitmapDecoder: I have tried that both when I did follow Microsoft's documentation and when I wrote a using block. Instead of using constructor of BmpBitMapDecoder, I used Create method of BitmapDecoder.
Result: This time, first, it complained about not being able to implicitly convert between BmpBitMapDecoder and BitMapDecoder. So I used type casting: "(BmpBitmapDecoder)". When I added casting however, it gave me another exception about not being able to convert between PngBitmapDecoder and BmpBitmapDecoder.

Why are you explicitly using a BitmapDecoder at all, instead of passing the Uri to the constructor of a BitmapImage, like BitmapSource bmpSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagesInDir[0]));?

The "exception about not being able to convert between PngBitmapDecoder and BmpBitmapDecoder" seems to indicate that your files are actually PNG files, not BMP. Be aware that the decoder is selected according to the type of stream (indicated by the first couple of bytes), regardless of any possible file extension.

@Clemens I also want to have a pointer to first pixel data of Bitmap (using Scan0 with a BitMapData instance). Regarding my images being PNG files, when I look at the images I see .bmp extension on images

You would have to call the CopyPixels method of the BitmapSource, no matter whether you create a BitmapImage or a BitmapFrame. BitmapData.Scan0 is not WPF, but System.Drawing (of WinForms).

And the file extension is irrelevant, as already said.

The image files you are trying to load are apparently PNG files, despite their file extension.
You should write code that is unaware of the actual format. Use the BitmapDecoder class like this:
IEnumerable<string> imagesInDir = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
    myPath, "*.bmp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

string firstImage = imagesInDir.FirstOrDefault();

if (firstImage != null)
{
    Uri imgURI = new Uri(firstImage);

    BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(
        imgURI, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

    BitmapSource bitmap = decoder.Frames[0];
}

Or do not explictly create a BitmapDecoder at all:
BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
    imgURI, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

or
BitmapSource bitmap = new BitmapImage(imgURI);


If you explicitly create a decoder, you may add a line like shown below to find out what type it actually is.
Debug.WriteLine(decoder.CodecInfo.FriendlyName);


It solved my problem. Thanks.
